# Высота блока при разных разрешениях

Tags: html, css

Как сделать чтобы отступ при разных разрешениях был одинаковый?

Стили:

```
.header {
  background: url('../img/header.png');
  -moz-background-size: 110%;
  /* Firefox 3.6+ */
  -webkit-background-size: 110%;
  /* Safari 3.1+ и Chrome 4.0+ */
  -o-background-size: 110%;
  /* Opera 9.6+ */
  background-size: 110%;
  /* Современные браузеры */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
}
```

1920x1080

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1280x1024

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Высота блока через инспектор (1280x1024)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Указал height: 50vw; - решение ли?

Answer (score 0):

css: `.header {height: 100%; min-width: 110%;}`

Если помогло ставте лайк)

Comment: А можно просто подписаться?)